# I can't register server middleware in nuxt.config.ts

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

This is my nuxt.config.ts file

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        '@/assets/main.css'
    ],
    serverMiddleware: [
        '~/serverMiddleware/test'
      ]
})
```

but TypeScript throws this error:

```
Argument of type '{ css: string[]; serverMiddleware: { path: string; handler: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NuxtConfig'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'serverMiddleware' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig'.ts(2345)
(property) serverMiddleware: {
    path: string;
    handler: string;
}[]`
```

I've looked in the docs and on YouTube, but I can't find out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `serverMiddleware` property does not exist in the Nuxt 3 configuration. That is why TypeScript is reporting an error about it. Additionally, you do not need to register server `middleware` manually as Nuxt automatically registers them. Just make sure that they reside in the `server/middleware` directory.

Here you can see which property you can add in [nuxt.config.ts](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config)